# Finding Vertices of a Polygonal Region

Tags: graphics, regions, geometry, version-10

I am trying to get a vertex list for a polygonal region made from the `RegionDifference` of two `Polygon`s, and I am unsure of how to do so. For example:

```
region1 = Polygon[{{310, 577.315}, {310, 708}, {228.998, 708},
                   {160, 588.451}, {160, 404}, {210.065, 404}}];
region2 = Polygon[{{101.341, 364.}, {330., 187.811}, {558.659, 364.}, {330., 760.283}}];
regionDiff = RegionDifference[region1, region2];
```

So, I'd like to find the vertices of `regionDiff`.

Other options for getting a vertex list for the difference of two polygons are also welcome.

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?  For version 11.2, `regionDiff` returns `Polygon[{{160., 465.66}, {299.832, 708.}, {228.998, 708.}, {160., 
   588.451}}]` directly.

Comment: I am using version 10.4.1.0. Version 11.2 sounds better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain the actual region with `R = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[regionDiff, MaxCellMeasure -> 100000]` or `R = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[regionDiff, Method -> "Boolean"]` (somehow depending on the version of Mathematica).

Afterwards, you can access properties of the `MeshRegion` `R` like with any other `MeshRegions`. For example, you obtain the coordinates with `MeshCoordinates[R]`.

Comment: I just tried this with the example Polygons and it gave me a list of 1752 points. The difference region is a quadrilateral.

Comment: @Frobryo - try `MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@regionDiff, 2]`

Comment: That works! To an extent. It's still giving more points than necessary (47 in the example), but they're all on the edge of the polygon and include the vertices, at least.

Comment: You can prevent subdivision by cranking up the value of `MaxCellMeasure`. Like this: `MeshPrimitives[
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[regionDiff, MaxCellMeasure -> 100000], 2]`

Comment: @Frobryo - this is odd.  When I use your example definition of `regionDiff` and the `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`, the result is a `Polygon` with four points, in version 10.3.1

Comment: @JasonB. I have version 11.0.1 and I also get more that four vertices when not enforcing large cell ares.

Comment: @JasonB very odd! I guess this must be an area that is/was being actively updated between versions.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, I can get it down to 10 points at MaxCellMeasure -> 10^10, it doesn't seem to want to do less than that.

Comment: Maybe `R = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[regionDiff, Method -> "Boolean"]` will work...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yes! That did it.

Answer (score 1):

In old versions (e.g. 10.4.1), you can use the *undocumented* function `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonComplement[] ``:

```
region1 = Polygon[{{310, 577.315}, {310, 708}, {228.998, 708},
                   {160, 588.451}, {160, 404}, {210.065, 404}}];
region2 = Polygon[{{101.341, 364.}, {330., 187.811}, {558.659, 364.}, {330., 760.283}}];
regionDiff = Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonComplement[region1, region2];

Graphics[{{Blue, region2}, {Red, region1}, {Green, regionDiff}}]
```

[image: polygons and their difference]